# Nested IF statement doesn't work like I want it to

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, var

```
var dayInput = document.querySelector("#day");
var monthInput = document.querySelector("#month");
var yearInput = document.querySelector("#year");
var day = document.querySelector("h2");
var h3 = document.querySelector("h3");

function runCode() {
dayPicked = Number(dayInput.value);
monthPicked = Number(monthInput.value);
yearPicked = Number(yearInput.value);
if (dayPicked <= 31) {
    if (monthPicked <= 12) {
        if ((monthPicked = 2) && (dayPicked <= 29)) {
            day.textContent = (DispDay(dayPicked, monthPicked, yearPicked));
            h3.textContent = (DispFullDate(dayPicked, monthPicked, 
yearPicked));
        } else { day.textContent = "Not Possible Dude!"}
    } else { day.textContent = "Not Possible Dude!"}
} else { day.textContent = "Not Possible Dude!"}
}
```

This is a snippet out of my code where I am trying to limit the search for dates within my input boxes. For example, if February is chosen and the day is the 30th, it should throw out an error. But all that happens with the code you see above is no matter what month I choose, it keeps returning February. I know I am definitely doing something wrong, but I do not know what it is. BTW - I started learning JavaScript 3 weeks ago so I know my code is a mess. Thanks.

```
var button = document.querySelector("#goButton");

[dayInput, monthInput, yearInput].forEach(function (element) {element.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    runCode();
    }
});
```

});

I don't know if the EventListener needs to be added here but here it is anyway.

Comment: typo `monthPicked = 2` If you run a linter, it would pick this stuff up.

Comment: Sidenote: Months are zero-based inside Date objects, so January is month 0 and month 12 does not exist. So the logic will have to take care of it once you create a Date object from the inputs.

Comment: Common error avoidable with the constant on the left so if(2 = monthPicked) can't be an assignment. (For better code do a ValidDate function which returns true or false.)

Answer (score 1):

You're *setting* `monthPicked`

```
monthPicked = 2
```

You meant to use two `==` to check for equality.

However, the next problem you'll see is that your code will only work if the user selects February.

You probably wanted

```
if ((monthPicked != 2) || (dayPicked <= 29)) {
```

That way if they select february, it has to be before 29th. Any other month can be anything. Still incomplete logic as some months should allow 31 others not. But i'll leave that to you. (Also, leap years!)

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated kind Sir!

Answer (score 0):

= is an Assignment Operator. == is an Equal To Operator,compares value of left and side expressions. Change monthPicked = 2 to monthPicked == 2.